# Score of players does not appear on game center

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4, game-center

I have a problem in game center with my app. Each player's score is not showing up as shown in the image link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCCFF.jpg

On iTunes Connect I have created a leaderboard, and when someone enters the game appears on the screen that is logged in the game center, but the score does not appear on the game center ...

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: code of which part of app ? game kit ??

Comment: Please post the code you're using to attempt to address the problem, the code that seems not to be working for you. Please also tag your questions with the language you're using (Is it Objective-C? JavaScript? Swift? Something else?). Cheers.